# stopping cassandra with ps auwx | grep cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

The documentation says:

ps auwx | grep cassandra
sudo kill

Using:
ps auwx | grep cassandra

result in 50 lines or more, how to pick the right number:

/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.6.jar -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1004M -Xmx1004M -Xmn200M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k -XX:StringTableSize=1000003 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:CompileCommandFile=/etc/cassandra/hotspot_compiler -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000 -XX:+UseCondCardMark -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7199 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=7199 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra -Dcassandra.storagedir= -cp /etc/cassandra:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/airline-0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-16.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.6.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/javax.inject.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.2.jar:/usr/share/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you missed first line of outputs. When executing the ps command, you should see the first line like following:

$ ps auwx | grep cassandra

username          18420   0.3  5.1  7486912 857400 s000  S+   10:17am

The number 18420 is the id that should be killed.

$ kill -9 *your_id*

Alternative, you could start Cassandra in foreground mode:

$ cassandra -f

Then you can just press ctrl+c to end the Cassandra.